# What are the downsides of using vyper and truffle together

Tags: truffle, vyper

Recently I read an article [Vyper+Truffle](https://medium.com/@johngrant/ethereum-vyper-development-using-truffle-73781c4d81d5) and wanted to build a token deployer using vyper contracts.

I was wondering if anyone knew the current downsides of using Vyper and truffle together?

Is it better to simply write and deploy vyper smart contracts and then interact with them from the front-end?

Comment: If you like python more you should check [populus](https://github.com/ethereum/populus). The only disadvantage of vyper is that it is less used than solidity and solidity is more 'mature'.